# How to override a the generator for factory_bot?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, factory-bot

I just copied [factory_bot's model_generator](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_bot_rails/blob/master/lib/generators/factory_bot/model/model_generator.rb) to my file #lib/generators/factory_bot/model/model_generator.rb

This was going to be my baseline to start making changes.
I was able to prove that it was reading my file by changing

require "generators/factory_bot"
require "factory_bot_rails"

```
module FactoryBot
  module Generators
    class ModelGenerator < FactoryBot::Generators::Base
      puts 'my file'
      def factory_definition
        <<~RUBY
          factory :#{factory_name}#{explicit_class_option} do
            #{factory_attributes.gsub(/^/, "    ")} # HERE IS WHERE I AM CALLING factory_attributes
          end
        RUBY
      end

      def factory_attributes # THIS METHOS IS NOT FOUND
        attributes.map { |attribute|
          "#{attribute.name} { #{attribute.default.inspect} }"
        }.join("\n")
      end
    end
  end
end
```

I am able to get my puts value but I also get this error

**undefined local variable or method `factory_name' for #FactoryBot::Generators::ModelGenerator:0x00007f90c367b7f8 (NameError)**

I am unsure how to move forward.

Comment: There might be some weird namespacing issue. Double check if `Base` is actually the Base you're looking for. Since it's not a fully qualified name, ruby might find another class called `Base` rather than the one you're expecting. Always using fully qualified names would avoid this.

Comment: Thanks, I just updated the `base` with `class ModelGenerator < FactoryBot::Generators::Base` and I am still getting the same problem.  and Thanks, I do  appreciate the help

Comment: What is the code that is calling this? i.e. where is it being used? could this be an error in the actual factory definition itself or the way the definition is being called rather than an error with the configuration?

Comment: I deleted my file and try the generator and it worked perfectly. then I added my file and same error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you should try not do add to lib/generators/factory_bot/model/model_generator.rb

file but you should create custom factories at lib/templates/factory_bot/model/factories.erb

```
FactoryBot.define do
  factory :<%= "#{class_name.gsub("::", "").underscore}#{explicit_class_option}" %> do
<%=
  attributes.map { |attribute|
results = "    #{attribute.name} "
    if attribute.name == 'name'
      results = results + "{ Faker::Name.name }"
    elsif 
      ...
    else
      results = results + "{ #{attribute.default.inspect} }"
    end
results
  }.join("\n")
%>
  end
end
```